# TableContinuationToken not getting Deserialised from JSON correctly

Tags: json, azure, azure-table-storage

I am having trouble trying to retrieve large datasets from Azure TableStorage. After several attempts at trying to get it in one go I have given up and am now using the TableContinuation Token, which is now not getting Deserialized correctly.The object is getting created but all the Next... values (i.e. NextRowKey, NextPartitionKey, etc are NULL, when the in `stringresponse` that gets created you can see the values it should be populating with...

The class I am passing contains a list of objects and the token

```
public class FlorDataset 
{
    public List<FlorData> Flors { get; set; }
    public TableContinuationToken Token { get; set; }
}
```

The controller code is not exactly rocket science either....

```
        [HttpGet, Route("api/list/{token}")]
    public IHttpActionResult FindAll(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            TableContinuationToken actualToken = token == "None"
                ? null
                : new TableContinuationToken()
                {
                    NextPartitionKey = NextPartition,
                    NextRowKey = token,
                    NextTableName = NextTableName
                };

            var x = Run(actualToken);
            Flors = x.Flors;
            actualToken = x.Token;
            NextTableName = actualToken.NextTableName;
            NextPartition = actualToken.NextPartitionKey;

                return Flors != null
                    ? (IHttpActionResult)new IsoncOkResult<FlorDataset>(x, this)
                    : NotFound();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
            return NotFound();
        }
    }

    private  FlorDataset Run(TableContinuationToken token)
    {
        return _repo.GetAllByYear("2016", token) as FlorDataset;
    }
```

The calling code, which calls my fairly standard Web API 2 Controller is:

```
                do
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.NextRowKey))
                    {
                        response = await client.GetAsync("api/list/None");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response = await client.GetAsync($"api/list/{token.NextRowKey}");
                    }
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var stringresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlorDataset>(stringresponse);
                        token = ds.Token;
                        Flors.AddRange(ds.Flors);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        token = null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    token = null;
                }
            } while (token != null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is not the greatest solution, but it's the only thing that works so far in case anyone else is trying the same and stumbling across my question....

In the calling code bit you do a horrible bit of string replacement before you do the deserialisation.... I actually feel dirty just posting this, so if anyone comes up with a better answer, please feel free to share.....

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var stringresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    stringresponse = stringresponse.Replace(">k__BackingField", "");
    stringresponse = stringresponse.Replace("<", "");
    var ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlorDataset>(stringresponse);
    token = ds.Token;
    Flors.AddRange(ds.Flors);                      
}
```

Not nice, not pretty, but does work!!!! :-D Going to wash my fingers with bleach now!!!